# Instead of using ls, how does it make work with `find`?

Tags: find, ls

I have this command:

```
ls -Ra | grep -cve/ -e'^\.*$'
```

and I would like to do exactly the same with `find`

I tried this `find . -name "^\.*$"  -o -print | wc -l`
but the problem is, if I create new file like this: `touch "^.*$"`
It will not work out the same way.

Please, any idea, how to change it to make it work the same?

Comment: I think that I have found out where is the problem. in `-e`. But what difference it makes?

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

What are you trying to do? Let me try to explain your command so I understand it:

`ls -Ra | grep -cve/ -e'^\.*$'` will give you:

- The number of files, directories, symbolic links, ...
- Including the current directory
- **Excluding files with names only consisting of dots:** `touch '...'` **(!!!)**

### The solution

If you want to do the **exactly the same** with `find`, you can use:

```
find . -not -regex '^\.+$' | wc -l
```

If the more-than-two-dots files thing is a mistake, this is it:

```
find . | wc -l
```

Or (theoretically) the 'ls' way by using the following - making the `a` uppercase won't print current and parent directory:

```
ls -RA | grep -cve/ -e^\$
```

### A little bit about timing

```
               except multidots    all files    number of files
  ls /home                0.75s        0.70s            ~330000
find /home                0.50s        0.50s            ~330000
  ls /                    2.50s        2.50s           ~1350000
find /                    1.90s        1.70s           ~1350000
  ls / [BSD]             10.00s        8.50s            ~250000
find / [BSD]              7.50s        7.50s            ~250000
```

You can see, find is pretty much always faster. *But we didn't optimize it yet!*

Adding the option `-f` to `ls` skips sorting and thus speeds up the process by approximately 30% (yielding **1.60s** for `/`), making `ls -RAf | grep -cve/ -e^\$` the fastest one of the commands. However, it seems to do nothing on FreeBSD...

Good to know: The extreme time difference when checking for multiple dots on BSD (FreeBSD in this case) probably originates mainly from the way [GNU Grep works and the fact that it's a lot faster](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html).
The longer times on BSD vs Linux probably are just because the BSD machine I tested this on is a lot slower, and maybe also because it's using another file system.

### TL;DR

The fastest command to get the number of all filesystem nodes inside a directory with standard tools on Linux is:

```
ls -RAf | grep -cve/ -e^\$
```

A shorter command which is also the faster one on FreeBSD (and, additionally, actually answers your question) is:

```
find . | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that if you use `-name` you only match against the basename of the file. From `man find`:

```
-name pattern
     Base of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading  directories
     removed)  matches  shell  pattern  pattern.   The metacharacters
     (`*', `?', and `[]') match a `.' at the start of the  base  name
     (this is a change in findutils-4.2.2; see section STANDARDS CON‐
     FORMANCE below). <snip>
```

To get similar behaviour as when using `ls -Ra` you should be using `-regex`:

```
-regex pattern
     File  name  matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match
     on the whole path, not a search. <snip>
```